# CakePHP Auth prevents access to a controller

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have recently added auth to my application and can access all controllers expect for 1.

The controller exists in the acos table, the user (logged in with group_id = 1) is in the aros & the aros_acos table has been populated with `$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');` so in my world this should mean the user can access all controllers.

I dont get any errors (unless there is another way of producing errors) so its hard to put any code here that means anything.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? How do the lft & rght fields relate to things could there possibly be a problem here?

Comment: You could try to run `cake acl view aco` in a console to check that your ACO tree is correct.

Comment: Yeah it apears as expected when i run this

Answer (score 0):

After backwards debugging through the acl class I finally managed to find the problem.

It turns out I had an action with the same name as the controller that was being blocked so when the db::check was run it returned a confused set of results with 2 different controllers (the correct one and the controller containing the action).